# Why is this question a test in "reopen votes"

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits, vote-to-reopen

So here we have following question:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/3726724

Which has:
- no edit visible in review
- no comments indicating that there is any discussion about question value

I understand that it may have been closed for wrong reasons, but that doesn't mean it is suitable for review test!

Yes, it's detailed, yes it's long, but hey - someone voted to close it in the first place? As a reviewer I see no reason why question which was once closed should be reopened just because (and why someone made a test out of it)

Comment: I'd really like to hear from @minitech specifically

Comment: The question is open... and is not closed (never has been), which is why it's a test. If your attitude is really that no question should be reopened if someone voted to close it in the first place can you please not use the re-open queue?

Answer (score 11):

There are 2 ways that a question can enter the reopen queue

- It recieves a reopen vote
- It is edited (within 7 days of closure)

**None of that should matter**. The question you should ask yourself is if it should be closed, everything else is just extra secondary information.

So (as far as the audit is concerned), this question was incorrectly closed, someone voted to reopen it and you attempted to dequeue it; keeping an incorrectly closed question closed.

In conclusion; do not use other peoples votes to decide how to vote yourself

Comment: I understand that, however should't it be marked that question received reopen vote, and why? Current way it works seems counter-intuitive for me.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel Why would it matter. It shouldn't factor into your decision

Comment: So why are there numbers of votes shown in close votes? It counters your point

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel I'm enclined to agree, you shouldn't use them to inform your decision either (apart from custom reasons, it which it makes sense to use existing custom reasons where appropriate).

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel Look at it this way. I'm a judge, I recieve an appeal from someone who has been sentenced to life in prison. I look at the evidence folder; it's empty. Do I (a) say; "there's no new evidence, appeal rejected", or (b) say; "There's no evidence, release this person"

Comment: @Michael the very point of reviewing is to bring an unbiased, independent viewpoint on the table, unfazed by any judgements others have made or not made. Reviewing is supposed to be a *corrective* for a system that will occasionally fail

Answer (score 7):

It's a test to make sure you're paying attention.  Review audits are posts that are known to be either good or bad that are inserted randomly into the review queue as a check to make sure users are reviewing correctly.  If you fail enough audits, your reviewing privileges will be suspended temporarily. This is designed to stop people from just clicking randomly or selecting the same option every time just to get the review badges.

Comment: You missed the point.

Comment: @Michael how so, can you elaborate?